# Is it necessary to Initialize a statement using MySQLi and PHP Prepared Statements

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have seen some tutorials on the web about using PHP Prepared Statements and MySQLi. some are using the `mysqli_stmt mysqli::stmt_init()` like:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init();
```

to call `prepare()` and other properties and methods of prepared statement

and some are not initilaizing like

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO CodeCall (FirstName, LastName) values (?, ?)")) {}
```

now my question is , is it necessary to initialize an object to be used?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not necessary.  I use MySQLi all the time and have never used that method.  You can simply use `mysqli::prepare` like you've seen in those examples.

[The documentation says](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.stmt-init.php):

> Allocates and initializes a statement object suitable for mysqli_stmt_prepare().
>
> Any subsequent calls to any mysqli_stmt function will fail until mysqli_stmt_prepare() was called.

So it sounds like this is the "manual" way to create a prepared statement, because it requires more steps.  The other `mysqli::prepare` method handles it in one step.

Comment: Thanks Josiah, but is your mean by  the "manual" way the "Procedura" way?l

Comment: @Suffii No, what I meant is that from what the documentation says, it sounds like `mysqli::prepare` probably _calls_ `mysqli::stmt_init` and then calls `mysqli_stmt::prepare`.  In other words, you can call those two methods yourself, or you can just call `mysqli::prepare` in one step, which will automatically call the other two anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It *might* be necessary. I recently ran into an issue where I was doing it this way:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare
```

And this worked on my local VM. It worked on our staging server. But it refused to work on the server we set up for the client to test. This server for the client was an exact clone of the staging server so it should have worked. After debugging I found that $stmt was never initialized so the application would always bomb out when $stmt->execute(); was called.

But doing it manually worked on all servers and locally:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init();
$stmt->prepare($sql);
```

I have no idea why the first method did not work consistently. Felt like sharing though, seemed relevant.